# Navigation Experimental Stack

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I was trying to make eband_local_planner to get it worked.

As I understand from the code, it is implemented as a plugin to ROS base local planner.

Can you please advise on how to get it to work ?
Should I launch something like the below ?

also, what needs to be added in the manifest file.

Best Regards
Praveen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34744/navigation-experimental-stack/) by [RamAlien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2451/ramalien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your launch file, add the following parameter to your `move_base` node:

```
<node name="move_base" type="move_base" pkg="move_base">
    ...
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0